# Java files are shown weird in Android Studio editor

Tags: java, android

I have installed Android Studio 1.4. Unfortunately Java files are shown weird in the editor like below:

[image]

This code is fine when I open the MainActivty.java. For example: when I open with notepad it looks like this:

```
package com.danishjo.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

I use Java 8 JDk version `jdk1.8.0_74`.
Android Studio file format is UTF8
I don't want to reinstall the Android Studio.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: update your android studio

Comment: change encoding type

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I use the same version on my other computer with same constraints. It is working. I don't want to update entire program. Is there any other way?

Comment: @war_Hero encoding type is UTF8

Comment: maybe update is the only option left, try doing it it something within 1.4. Also make sure the file is not corrupted by opening it inn other IDE

Comment: there wont be any issue in update..so update it

Comment: How did you find Android Studio 1.4? There are 2 versions available right now. 2.3.3 and 3.0 Canary Preview.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help > Check Update >

You need to update your android studio.

**OR**

Try Invalidate Cache and restart